# CryptographicException in StateDataFormat.Unprotect()

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

*I recently posted a question which has been answered but led to this new problem. If interested, it can be seen at [Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370187/how-do-i-send-a-value-through-ad-b2c-using-openid-connect).*

**Intro**

I am currently developing an application using AD-B2C as my identity provider. This is integrated into the solution using their guidelines at AD B2C graph, which uses openid-connect.

I need to use a form of email activation (outside of their register policy) and as such I need to be able to pass a value from the URL in the email, through the sign-up process at B2C and back to the redirection URL.

For this we use the state parameter.

**Problem**

In my **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** I encrypt the state

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var temp = notification.ProtocolMessage.State;
        // To be used later
        var mycustomparameter = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("mycustomparameter");

        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.State != null)
        {
            var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
            var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
            var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
            state.Dictionary.Add("mycustomparameter", "testing");
            notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

This works for all I can tell.

Now the user is passed to the sign in on the **AD B2C** and is after the login redirected back where the **OnMessageReceived** is triggered.

```
 private Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        string mycustomparameter;
        var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];

        var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
        state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("mycustomparameter", out mycustomparameter);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

this is where it breaks. In the *...StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState)*

It throws an error **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException** with the message "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

**EDIT:  Stacktrace:**

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(System.Func<byte[], byte[]> func, byte[] input)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(System.Web.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider, byte[] protectedData, string[] purposes) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData, string[] purposes)    Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DataProtection.MachineKeyDataProtector.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)  Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.AppBuilderExtensions.CallDataProtectionProvider.CallDataProtection.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)   Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.SecureDataFormat<Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties>.Unprotect(string protectedText)  Unknown
```

> IntellifyPortal.dll!IntellifyPortal.Startup.OnMessageReceived(Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications.MessageReceivedNotification notification) Line 171    C#

**My attempts**

I have tried specifying machine keys in the **Web.config**

I have tried messing with the "**CallbackPath** property in **OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions**, with no success.

I have tried a lot of diffent tweaks, but I can't seem to figure out why I can't "unprotect" the inbound state.

*Any help is appreciated,*

*Best regards.*

**Update: Solution**

*I have decided to use an alternative method, which I found to work(hopefully it may of use to others):*
[Azure-sample which I used as guidance](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
        {
            notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken;
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
        }

        // Accept Invitation Email
        string testValue= notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("testValue");
        string testValue2= notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("testValue2");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue2))
        {
            var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
            var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
            var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
            state.Dictionary.Add("testValue", testValue);
            state.Dictionary.Add("testValue2", testValue2);
            notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        // Extract the code from the response notification
        var code = notification.Code;

        string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);

            // Look for acceptInvitation
            string testValue;
            string testValue2;

            var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
            var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
            state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("testValue", out testValue);
            state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("testValue2", out testValue2);

            // InvitationAccept / store values
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue2))
            {
                // How can I pass values to the redirect controller?
                // Can I somehow transfer it from here to that destination
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Handle
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Final Question**

I can now receive the values back as expected. These values has to be used in creating a relation between the new account and other accounts/groups in the application.

I therefore want to transfer these values **back** to the application (controller) for processing. I've tried storing the values in the context, in the response headers and in the claims to no avail. I guess this is because that this is the "middleware" and that the actual "redirect" happens directly from **AD B2C** thus not holding my params.

Can I somehow get the params back to the controller as well, without relying on the request URI (originating from the original user link) - Preferably directly in the claims, so that a user already logged in does not have to "re-signin" upon clicking the link.

**How can I get my values (in the state, which are handled in the OnMessageRecieved) passed to the controller which is redirected to?**

Comment: Can you share an example of the value that you're passing in as protectedState, both to Protect() and to Unprotect()

Comment: @Saca I update the solution using a different method which works (without the endless cryptographyErrors. I do however have a question I would like your comment on as well (see update if you have the time, I would appreciate it). I'll answer your question in any case. Examples of the params passed, an email address and a hashed token for validation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to decrypt the hint.  Instead of this:

```
ProtocolMessage.State.Split('
```

Remove the hint so you only have encrypted data:

`ProtocolMessage.State.Parameters["state"].Replace("OpenId.AuthenticationOptions=","")`

Then you can you decrypt value of sate:

StateDataFormat.Unprotect("TC%$t43tj9358utj3")

It should deserialize to AuthenticationOptions.